# In angular, dynamically change CSS properties?

Tags: angularjs

I am using a CSS selector `my-invalid` to indicate invalid elements.

```
.my_invalid{
   border-color:#ffdddd;
   background-color:#ffdddd;
   background-image: none;
  }
```

I would like to control when the elements use the invalid styling by modifying the selector. Is there a way to modify the actual selector properties in angular? Something along the lines of:

```
var my_invalid_props = CSS.find("my_invalid").properties;

...

CSS.find("my_invalid").properties = [];

....

CSS.find("my_invalid").properties = my_invalid_props;
```

Comment: Usually, [`ng-class`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) is the cleanest approach to dynamically changing CSS based on the viewmodel. Can you post the relevant parts of your html?

Comment: Even though ng-class would be best choice, for dynamic properties you can use ng-style. Call function on ng-style which returns set of properties with dynamic values & those values depend upon different model values.
https://plnkr.co/edit/BcLqxDKChD7fjqX9rfAH?p=preview